# Missing Gravity Form Fields

Tags: wordpress, css, gravity-forms-plugin

I accidentally hid the fields of the gravity form I created for my website footer, I think this happened when I added a CSScode to reduce the spacing between form fields.

Please how can I undo this, because all I can see is just the submit button and the form Widget title.

[Here's a link to the website if needed.](http://www.martcircle.com)

Also here's a screenshot to the footer widget:

[image]

Thanks

```css
body .gform_wrapper ul li.gfield {
        margin-top: 0px !important;
        padding-top: 0;
    }
    .block-content ul li {
          margin-bottom: 0 !important;
          margin-top: 0 !important;
        }
    .gform_body ul li .ginput_container select,.gform_body ul li .ginput_container input{
            margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .gform_wrapper .top_label .gfield_label {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Becky Abe. Have a look please have a look at my answer below, if it helps, please _accept_ the answer, alternatively, let me know if it didn't help so that we can continue trying to solve your problem :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't really gotten used to the platform that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fields are hidden thanks to a different rule in your stylesheet.

Inspecting the web element on your website showed me this:

*Line 159 inside your style.css*

```
.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_fields, .gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_column li.gsection:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Your first declaration: `.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_fields` is the parent container for the form fields inside gravity forms. Removing this (as well as the comma separating the 2 declarations ofcourse) will fix the issue.

For detailing purposes, that line of code would become:

```
.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_column li.gsection:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

I tested this in Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and it displays this:

[image: working solution]